# Error: futureInvestmentValue cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I have to create a program in Java that uses a method to compute future investment value with the user putting in the investment amount and interest rate.  It has to display in a table and have years `1-30`.

I have ONE error that I cannot figure out how to fix. The error is under `//Title` in the `main` where I have `futureInvestmentValue`. The error is telling me that

> futureInvestmentValue cannot be resolved to a variable

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class futureInvestmentValue {    
    public static double futureInvestmentValue(double investmentAmount, 
        double monthlyInterestRate, int years){
        double futureInvestmentValue = 1;

        for (years = 1; years <= 30; years++) {
            monthlyInterestRate = years/1200;
            futureInvestmentValue = 
                investmentAmount * Math.pow((1+monthlyInterestRate), years*12);
        }
        return futureInvestmentValue;
    }           

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Get investment amount and yearly interest rate from user
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter investment amount, for example 100:" + 
            "Enter yearly interest rate, for example 5.25:\n");
        double investmentAmount = input.nextDouble();
        double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

        //Title
        System.out.print("Years\t" + "\t Future Value");

        for (int years = 1; years <= 30; years++) {
            System.out.print(years);
            System.out.printf("%4d", futureInvestmentValue);

        }
        System.out.println();               
    }    
}
```

Comment: You declare that variable inside of `futureInvestmentValue()` so you can only access it in that method. If you want access in `main()` you need to declare it as a class variable that is static.  Another option is to call that method in your print statement by using `()` at the end.

Comment: yes, because it is not a variable, yet you use it as such.

Answer (score 5):

In your main method, you are referencing the variable instead of the function name...

```
System.out.printf("%4d", futureInvestmentValue);
```

The above should be:

```
System.out.printf("%4d", futureInvestmentValue(investmentAmount, ..... ));
```

That is what you get, by the way, for giving variables and functions the same name. Don't do it.

Comment: This is what happens when  Visual Basic is the first programming language you learn.